# SpagoBI + Firebird DataSource (The result set is closed)

Tags: firebird, jaybird, spagobi

I am using Spagobi version 3.6.0, Jaybird-2.2.2JDK_1.7 and Firebird 2.5 (x64). I set up a datasource and the testing is OK.

I set up a dataset and the preview shows the correct list of colunms, only there is no data. Access via some other SQL viewer shows the data.

The error message in the Catalina log is:

> ```
> org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLException: The result set is closed
> ```

Does anybody have an idea what I did wrong?

Comment: Try upgrading to Jaybird 2.2.7, make sure you are either using autoCommit=false, or are using holdable result sets.

Comment: Also: post some code (or if this is a tool: details on the config, etc).

Comment: You might be confronted with bugs [JDBC-304](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/JDBC-304) or [JDBC-305](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/JDBC-305) that were fixed in Jaybird 2.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some testing the solution to your problem is to specify the connection property `defaultHoldable=true` in the connection URL of the datasource, so for example:

```
jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost/database?defaultHoldable=true
```

As commented earlier you also need to upgrade to Jaybird 2.2.7, otherwise you will be confronted with bugs [JDBC-304](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/JDBC-304) and/or [JDBC-305](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/JDBC-305).

I haven't checked the code of SpagoBI, but it looks like SpagoBI assumes that result sets are always holdable over commit and executes its queries using auto commit. It should either not use auto commit, or check the `DatabaseMetaData.getResultSetHoldability()` and/or `Connection.getHoldability()` and explicitly request holdable result sets.

Comment: Hi Mark! Thank you so much! I got the problem solved after adding the  `?defaultHoldable=true` parameter. It worked with all Jaybird versions after doing that. Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Sorry about that, never have asked before ;)