# Impossible to generate metamodel in spagoBI studio with Firebird

Tags: jdbc, firebird, jaybird, spagobi

In SpagoBI Studio, after saving a connection that was ok with the result firebird database, showed no table in the schema. It is possible to connect with Squirrel.

Data of the local connection:

```
url: jdbc: FirebirdSQL: //localhost//var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/database.fdb defaultHoldable = true
user: sysdba
pass: xxxxxxxxx
```

also does not return for remote connection:

```
jdbc: FirebirdSQL: 10.114.0.130/3050: /data/samdb/database.fdb
```

Could someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Could you describe what you are doing (the steps you follow, and what happens or doesn't happen and what you expect, any errors you get)? Also check the logs of SpagoBI, when I tried it for [a previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30486267/spagobi-firebird-datasource-the-result-set-is-closed), it reported that it connected successfully, when in fact it didn't connect at all due to a Java class version error.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why are you using both URL formats? The first one is the normal format (and works both for local and remote connections), the second one is an old format that is only supported for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Thank you for responding so soon, but I did not found any errors in the logs, but I'm looking for. I will do the notes you asked.

Comment: Hello, concludes that it would be better to demonstrate through a video that is in this link:

https://youtu.be/f8rOab2D3Q0

we have two database:
mysql -> gts can access the scheme of table names and their fields.
firebird -> scap_aip can not get the layout of tables and fields.
Thank you in advance

Comment: I haven't had the time to look at it yet, I will try to do that later this week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've got the same problem here.

After some searching I've found that Spago Studio doesn't allow you to install any software.

But this is not necessary in fact.

The solution:
Download Firebird DTP package from [Firebird DTP on GitHub](https://github.com/mrotteveel/fbdtp/releases/latest) then unzip the content into your SpagoBI (or any Eclipse plataform) /plugins/ directory and Firebird will be available in database's list for creating a new database connection.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to install the Firebird DTP Plugin first, because Eclipse DTP doesn't support Firebird natively. You can download the plugin from [Firebird DTP on GitHub](https://github.com/mrotteveel/fbdtp/releases/latest).

Comment: As far as I know SpagoBI doesn't use Eclipse DTP.

Comment: SpagoBI Studio is based on Eclipse and also DTP.

Comment: Are there multiple variants? When I looked at it for another question it was a web application, so I assumed it doesn't use Eclipse.

Comment: came another priority, but will return as soon as possible and continue with this project with SpagoBI Server and SpagoStudio Thanks.

Comment: Hello continuing:
To install the Firebird DTP Plugin as mentioned follow:
menu -> help -> install new software
but it appeared an error window with the message:

Software Updates
Can not complete the request. This installation has not Been configured properly for Software Updates see the error log for details.

the log window:

! MESSAGE Could not locate the running profile instance. The eclipse.p2.data.area and eclipse.p2.profile properties May Not Be Correctly in September this application's config.ini file.

I searched the internet how to solve this problem but have not succeeded.

Comment: @AlexandreNardelli That link (current and before my edit) is not an Eclipse update site, you need to download it manually and unzip it into the plugins folder.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, OK, with firebird_DTP plugins copied in SpagoStudio plugins, they managed to get the Schemas: SYSTEM and USER, however not with the database name and SpagoStudio can not get the field names, is there any optional parameter that would change the name USER's schema for the database name or some other way to access the names of the USER schema fields? look at this video:[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJLLyNonUNQ)

Comment: @AlexandreNardelli I don't understand what you mean with that (there is only one database: the one you are connecting to; so getting the name of the database doesn't make sense). Please consider posting a more detailed question, or mail to the Firebird-java mailinglist (which would be a better medium for troubleshooting).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Could you pass me the link of the Firebird-java mailinglist ? thanks in advance

Comment: @AlexandreNardelli Send an e-mail to firebird-java-subscribe@yahoogroups.com to subscribe